# "Open in Excel" prompt disabled when accessing workbook through office web apps

Tags: 2013, excel, office-web-apps

We're trying to share an excel workbook through SharePoint which sends a link through mail with "web=1" which calls for excel web access. since the document has unsupported features in OWA, it prompts us to open in Excel client,, but surprisingly the "open" button is disabled.
.[image: open in client button disabled]

things we tried:

1. "Open in Client" feature is enabled at the site collection.
2. Office 2013 is installed
3. Added the sites to trusted sites list in IE
4. verified on multiple browsers IE 11, Google Chrome and Firefox.
5. Have full control permissions.

We believe it's a bug,, do you have any clue about it or any workarounds?

Comment: does it happen only with the one that have unsupported by OWA features, or you cannot open any other Excel file from OWA as well?

Comment: Hello Andrey,, actually this dialog appears only when the document contains OWA unsupported features such as sheet protection,, otherwise the document opens normally.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this in the meantime? We are facing the same issue right now.

Comment: This bug is legit. I am also facing it now and so far now resolution in any posts. Did you manage to fix it?